# Can I start Hellblazer from any point?

Tags: suggested-order, vertigo-comics, hellblazer

Given that John Constantine was introduced on **The Saga of the Swamp Thing #37 (June 1985)**, had its launch title (***John Constantine, Hellblazer***) in 1988, ended in 2013 @ its' 300th issue and was relaunched that same year as DC Universe's **Constantine**, I'd like to know where to start from.

What reading order would be recommended and why? Is it required to start from the original #1 issue or can I start from the New 52 reboot in 2013?

Comment: From the beginning? Your question will need a bit more work before it can be answered adequately.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that reading it from the first appearance isn't acceptable?

Comment: @Valorum I could've written that too...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're hoping to learn here. There's nothing to stop you from starting at the start or the 2013 reboot. Both are intended as "entry points" for the comic.

Comment: @Valorum ok, thanks. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: Page 1 perhaps?

Comment: @Human_AfterAll - The "New 52" comics were designed to act as a new start for all of Marvel's top characters. If you're interested in the Contantine/Hellblazer continuity, [Constantine #1](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/constantine-2013/constantine-1) would be a good point to start. It's not as grim & inaccessible as the original imprint. There were only 25 of these, then they rebooted again with [Contantine: The Hellblazer](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/constantine-the-hellblazer-2015/constantine-the-hellblazer-1) in 2015. Get caught up with those, then loop around to the original imprint.

Comment: @Valorum Would mind posting this as an answer?

Comment: _sigh_ Start at Hellblazer 1# and read as long as you'll still want to. Don't bother with new versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a brand new reader to the Hellblazer franchise, the most obvious point to join the character is the 2013 'New 52' reboot under the banner "[**Constantine #1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Constantine#The_New_52)". This serial ran for two years (and 23 issues) and was immediately followed by another softer reboot as [Constantine: The Hellblazer](http://www.dccomics.com/comics/constantine-the-hellblazer-2015/constantine-the-hellblazer-1) in 2015, complete with large elements designed to tie into the TV series.

The New 52 serial was specifically designed to serve as an "entry point" for new readers, providing enough "easter egg" material to please existing fans, but intentionally requiring zero knowledge of the character for new fans to enjoy the comics.

> **CV:** *Is this* [The New 52] *going to be a good starting point for new readers or
> should they start with more recent issues of JLD?*
>
> **RF:** *CONSTANTINE #1 was written with an eye to the notion that readers
> may be picking it up without ever having read Justice League Dark, and
> I think it works very well that way. Our goal, really, is to make sure
> that each of the two books enriches the other without impinging on it,
> so you'll never <sup>∗</sup>need<sup>∗</sup> to be reading both, but if you do, you'll
> hopefully enjoy them both more.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview: Ray Fawkes Discusses the New CONSTANTINE Series](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/john-constantine/4005-3329/forums/interview-ray-fawkes-discusses-the-new-constantine-745542/)</sup></sub>

So my suggested order would be

- [**Constantine**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Constantine_Vol_1) #1 - #23
- [**Constantine: The Hellblazer**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Constantine:_The_Hellblazer_Vol_1) - #1 - #13
- [**Justice League Dark**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Justice_League_Dark_Vol_1) #1 - #40
- [**Hellblazer**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Hellblazer_Vol_1) #1 - #300

etc.